# Can't pass GET parameter while unit testing Zend Framework 2

Tags: get, routes, zend-framework2, phpunit

I'm having hard time trying to unit test ([phpUnit](http://phpunit.de)) one of my modules in [ZF2](http://framework.zend.com/). What I'm trying to do is determine whether a classname is present on one of the elements on page when a **GET parameter** is passed to the controller.

It all works from the browser, however I can't get the GET parameter to be recognized at all when trying to unit test.

This is my code for unit testing:

```
<?php

namespace ComponentManager\Controller;
use Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase;

class ComponentManagerControllerTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setApplicationConfig(
            include 'config/application.config.php'
        );
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testAdminComponentCodeCanBeAccessed()
    {
        $this->dispatch('/ComponentManager/requestComponent/product/details-1/details-1', 'GET', array('admin' => 1));
        // I also tried: $this->dispatch('/ComponentManager/requestComponent/product/details-1/details-1?admin=1');
        $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
        $this->assertMatchedRouteName('ComponentManager/path');
        $this->assertControllerName('ComponentManager\Controller\ComponentManager');
        $this->assertControllerClass('ComponentManagerController');
        $this->assertActionName('requestComponent');
        $this->assertModuleName('ComponentManager');

        // test will fail here
        $this->assertQuery('div.config-active-wrapper');
    }
}
```

The **"div.config-active-wrapper"** selector works fine when I remove the check for admin parameter presence in GET but when I re-add it, the GET parameter doesn't get recognised at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that unit testing is a **CLI** operation and no superglobals are being populated while in CLI. Simple and stupid :P

A **solution** is to *not use superglobals* like *$_GET* here but to pass this "admin" parameter via some ACL and a controller instead.

Comment: You shouldn't use superglobals in your controller anyway, you should be accessing the var using `$this->params()->fromQuery('admin');`, which might fix your test problem.

Comment: that's what I'm planning on doing once I have some ACL there ;)